# Pull down / autofill a list of dates, but only weekdays, not weekends - excel

Tags: excel

Ive want to pull down a list of dates in excel to auto fill a bunch of rows eg. type 03/03/17 and then pull down the cell to auto populate the dates all the way through march.

Normally this is straight forward, but in this instance im trying to get all of the workdays only and no weekend dates, how could that be done automatically without having to input all dates and remove rows where they fall on weekends ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula below your first date and then autofill the formula down.  make sure your first date is a weekday.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(A1+1)<>7,A1+1,A1+3)
```

How it works

WEEKDAY(A11+1)<>7 if the cell above + 1 day is not Saturday then add a day A1+1 else add 3 days to the cell above A1+3.

You can copy and paste as values once you have the dates you need.  You can also keep it as a template and change the first date to change all the dates below as required.

Answer (score 0):

The `WORKDAY(Start_date, Days [Holidays])` function returns the Monday to Friday dates based on a Start_date, number of days and optional Holidays array of dates.

Data Validation allows you to create a list of comma separated items or a named range of cells.

Create a list of Public Holidays in a column and name the range `Holidays`.

Enter a workday date in a cell (say G2) and in the cell below it (G3), enter this formula:

`=WORKDAY(G2,1,Holidays)`

Copy the formula down for about 65 rows (i.e. to cover 3 months allowing 22 workdays per month).  Delete dates from the bottom of the list that are greater than your desired end date.  Select the dates and name it Workdays.

In the range that you want to have dropdown lists:
[image: Data Validation dialogue]